# How to remove some of "my tags"?

Tags: support, ignored-tags, my-tags

I happen to have answered to a regexp-related issue on stackoverflow which was *also* tagged oracle and oracle10g; this led to those two tags being in the "my tags" list and, thus, half of the questions I see in the [unanswered mytags](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags) page are related to Oracle which I know very little about and which, frankly, don't care much.

I tried using "Ignore Tags + Hide" but that only hides then, i.e. I see less than 10 answers per page, some times as little as 1 or 2 answers per page (the seems to be quite a few questions about Oracle indeed).

Is the a way to intentionally opt-out of unwanted side-effect tags?

EDIT to clarify:

I didn't select any Interesting tag at all so (I guess) it was using all the ones I answered to as a default. I didn't think to try and explicitly define Interesting ones: they actually would be all the 15 of them, except the 2 Oracle ones, so I was mostly happy with the previous list, but OTOH I can't control which side-tags are present on the questions I do answer, so it's probably better to chose Interesting tags explicitly.

Mhh, yes indeed: if I do add some explicit Interesting tags, the "not Interesting, not Ignored" tags are no more selected by default in that page.

OTOH now all the page's tags are yellow-backgrounded (as the Interesting tags are so, I guess) and is a bit of a color-fest, but oh well...

Comment: tl;dr: `if(isEmpty(my_favorite_tags)) use_tags_from_questions_I_answered else use_my_favorite_tags`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not seeing this behavior.

Specifically, if I find a tag 'A' that:

1. I have not added to my interested tags list and
2. I have answered a question on in the past

and I go to the Unanswered button and allow it to fall on the My Tags tab, I do not see 'A' tagged questions in my result set.

Are you certain that other tags that you *have* set as interesting are not also included in these Oracle* questions?

Comment: Mhh, yes indeed: if I do add some explicit Interesting tags, the "normal" tags are no more selected by default in that page. Not totally satisfying, but I guess it's a matter of habit.

Comment: OK, now that I've replied to many more "not really interesting" side-tags, I really do appreciate that "my tags" shows only the tags I do want. ;)