# Can I directly control "My Tags"?

Tags: feature-request, my-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove some of “my tags”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19497/how-to-remove-some-of-my-tags)

Having answered an iTunes-related question I now have [osx] as one of My Tags, and my Unanswered display is now 90% OSX questions...but I don't use or know anything about OS X. I added the tag to my Ignored list and set it to hide ignored tags, but that doesn't solve the problem, because the Unanswered list is still using [osx] in its selection criteria -- it just hides the matching articles in its display.

My profile's Stats page lists My Tags but doesn't let me delete them, and the Prefs page lets me manage Interesting or Ignored tags but not the "My" Tags.  Is there any way to remove this tag from the My Tags list?  If not, is there any chance one might be added?

(Well, oops. This is apparently a [dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19497/how-to-remove-some-of-my-tags). Didn't think of the "my-tags" tag until I was tagging my own question...)